# Haskell cassava (Data.Csv): Ignore missing columns/fields

Tags: csv, haskell

How can I set up cassava to ignore missing columns/fields and fill the respective data type with a default value? Consider this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import           Data.Csv
import           Data.Vector
import           GHC.Generics

data Foo = Foo { 
      a :: String
    , b :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
    
instance FromNamedRecord Foo

decodeAndPrint :: ByteString -> IO ()
decodeAndPrint csv = do
    print $ (decodeByName csv :: Either String (Header, Vector Foo))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    decodeAndPrint "a,b,ignore\nhu,1,pu"  -- [1]
    decodeAndPrint "ignore,b,a\npu,1,hu"  -- [2]
    decodeAndPrint "ignore,b\npu,1"     -- [3]
```

`[1]` and `[2]` work perfectly fine, but `[3]` fails with

```
Left "parse error (Failed reading: conversion error: no field named \"a\") at \"\""
```

How could I make `decodeAndPrint` capable of handling this incomplete input?

I could of course manipulate the input bytestring, but maybe there is a more elegant solution.

---

A **Solution** thanks to the input of Daniel Wagner below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import           Data.Csv
import           Data.Vector
import           GHC.Generics

data Foo = Foo { 
      a :: Maybe String
    , b :: Maybe Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
    
instance FromNamedRecord Foo where
    parseNamedRecord rec = pure Foo
        <*> ((Just <$> Data.Csv.lookup rec "a") <|> pure Nothing)
        <*> ((Just <$> Data.Csv.lookup rec "b") <|> pure Nothing)

decodeAndPrint :: ByteString -> IO ()
decodeAndPrint csv = do
    print $ (decodeByName csv :: Either String (Header, Vector Foo))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    decodeAndPrint "a,b,ignore\nhu,1,pu"  -- [1]
    decodeAndPrint "ignore,b,a\npu,1,hu"  -- [2]
    decodeAndPrint "ignore,b\npu,1"       -- [3]
```

Comment: Make your fields `Maybe String`/`Maybe Int`?

Comment: This is unfortunately not enough. Cassava does not handle this automatically also for Maybe - I tried. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Warning: completely untested! Code is for idea transmission only, not suitable for any use, etc. etc.)

The `Parser` type demanded by `FromNamedRecord` is an `Alternative`, so just toss a default on with `(<|>)`.

```
instance FromNamedRecord Foo where
    parseNamedRecord rec = pure Foo
        <*> (lookup rec "a" <|> pure "missing")
        <*> (lookup rec "b" <|> pure 0)
```

If you want to know later whether the field was there or not, make your fields rich enough to record that:

```
data RichFoo = RichFoo
    { a :: Maybe String
    , b :: Maybe Int
    }

instance FromNamedRecord Foo where
    parseNamedRecord rec = pure RichFoo
        <*> ((Just <$> lookup rec "a") <|> pure Nothing)
        <*> ((Just <$> lookup rec "b") <|> pure Nothing)
```